# IPython "Column not found error"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I group a dataframe based on the fields 'MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress' and then find the difference between consecutive dates of each group.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress', 'DateTime'])['DateTime'].agg(['count']).reset_index()
df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateTime'])
df2['timedif'] = df2['DateTime'].diff()
```

It works well for first group, but for second group, it does not start from the beginning, rather it subtracts the DateTime from the DateTime of its previous record which is of a different group.

Current output:

```
MachineName LocalIPAddress      DateTime               count timedif
0   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 03:42:29.865  1  NaT 
1   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 08:48:33.005  1  05:06:03.140000 
2   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 10:16:28.612  1  01:27:55.607000 
3   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 10:31:33.343  1  00:15:04.731000
4   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 23:43:12.068  1  13:12:56.580000 
5   BMTSYSP05   10.20.9.253     2016-04-13 06:08:53.584  1  -1 day +06:25:41
6   BMTSYSP05   10.20.9.253     2016-04-13 12:01:57.563  1  05:53:03.979000
```

Expected output:

```
MachineName LocalIPAddress      DateTime               count timedif
0   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 03:42:29.865  1   NaT    
1   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 08:48:33.005  1   05:06:03.140000    
2   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 10:16:28.612  1   01:27:55.607000    
3   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 10:31:33.343  1   00:15:04.731000
4   BMTSAFT04   10.18.0.186     2016-04-13 23:43:12.068  1   13:12:56.580000    
5   BMTSYSP05   10.20.9.253     2016-04-13 06:08:53.584  1   NaT
6   BMTSYSP05   10.20.9.253     2016-04-13 12:01:57.563  1   05:53:03.979000
```

The 5th row belongs to a different group, so the time difference should not be -1 day +06:25:41, it has to be NaT. I need the difference logic to be applied for each grouping.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: MachineName LocalIPAddress SourceAddress DateTime


BMTSAFT04 10.3.0.186 10.20.4.51 2016-04-13 03:42:29.865 \\


BMTSAFT04 10.3.0.186  10.20.4.51  2016-04-13 08:48:33.005 \\


BMTSAFT04 10.3.0.186  10.20.4.51 2016-04-13 10:16:28.612 \\

BMTSAFT04 10.3.0.186  10.20.4.51 2016-04-13 10:31:33.343 \\


BMTSAFT04 10.3.0.186 10.20.4.51 2016-04-13 13:43:00.173 \\

This is the output of a dataframe. I need to find the difference between two subsequent DateTimes. For example, difference between second and first DateTimes is 5 hours and 6 minutes. Similarly, i have to do this for all the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following is your dataframe:

```
    MachineName LocalIPAddress  SourceAddress   DateTime
0   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 03:42:29.865
1   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 08:48:33.005
2   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 10:16:28.612
3   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 10:31:33.343
4   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 13:43:00.173
```

You can first convert the `DateTime` column if it's not already of type datetime:

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])
```

After that you can directly get the difference using the diff() function:

```
df["timedif"] = df["DateTime"].diff()

    MachineName LocalIPAddress  SourceAddress   DateTime                  timedif
0   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 03:42:29.865   NaT
1   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 08:48:33.005   05:06:03.140
2   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 10:16:28.612   01:27:55.607
3   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 10:31:33.343   00:15:04.731
4   BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186      10.20.4.51      2016-04-13 13:43:00.173   03:11:26.830
```

diff() returns a timedelta object which apparently lacks some of the methods including strftime so I converted it to datetime again with `df["timedif"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timedif"])` to format the date. This may not be a good idea if you are working with yearly differences.

```
df["timedif"] = df["timedif"].dt.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Out:

```
0      NaT
1    05:06
2    01:27
3    00:15
4    03:11
Name: timedif, dtype: object
```

### Edit:

Based on your last sample input, you don't need to group by `DateTime`, you can do this:

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])
df.groupby(["MachineName", "LocalIPAddress"])["DateTime"].diff()

0               NaT
1   05:06:03.140000
2   01:27:55.607000
3   00:15:04.731000
4   13:11:38.725000
5               NaT
6   05:53:03.979000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And as usual, you can add this result to the current dataframe:

```
df["timedif"] = df.groupby(["MachineName", "LocalIPAddress"])["DateTime"].diff()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!

I have the aggregation operation and then I am converting the DateTime column to a DateTime so that its of type DateTime.

df2 = df.groupby(['MachineName','LocalIPAddress','SourceAddress','DateTime'])['DateTime'].agg(['count'])


df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateTime'])

But I get the error as "duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality". I am not duplicating any columns here but not sure on how to rectify this error !!

I wonder couldn't I do the conversion after the aggregation operation.

Comment: The reason I am performing the aggregation is I want to group the rows with identical MachineName, LocalIPAddress, SourceAddress and DateTime. Then I need to find the difference between adjacent DateTimes of each group.

Comment: Try `df2 = df.groupby(["MachineName", "LocalIPAddress", "SourceAddress", "DateTime"], sort=False).count().reset_index()`

Comment: I grouped the dataframe based on 'MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress' and 'SourceAddress' and then find the difference between consecutive dates of each group. 

df2 = df.groupby(['MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress', 'SourceAddress', 'DateTime'])['DateTime'].agg(['count']).reset_index()


df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateTime'])


df2['timedif'] = df2['DateTime'].diff()


df2

It works well for first group, but for second group, it does not start from the beginning, rather it subtracts the DateTime from the DateTime of its previous record which is of a different group.

Comment: From your question ("I try to get the difference between the adjacent DateTimes") and your comment ("I need to find the difference between two subsequent DateTimes") I thought that was what you were asking. Can you edit your question to include expected output?

Comment: I group the dataframe and then find the difference between DateTimes of adjacent columns that belong to a group.

Comment: MachineName LocalAddress SourceAddress DateTime //

0 BMTSAFT04 10.20.0.186 2016-04-13 03:42:29.865 NaT //
1 BMTSAFT04 10.20.0.186 2016-04-13 08:48:33.005 05:06 //
2 BMTSAFT05 10.20.0.187 2016-04-13 10:16:28.612    01:27 //

For the third row, since it is of a different group, It should not subtract its DateTime from the second row, here I need the difference to be NaT. Hope thats clear.

Comment: Thank you. It would be so much easier if you edit your question instead of adding a comment. In the question you can use code formatting tools at the top so the input and output tables are readable. As for the groups, the grouping you stated in the question includes the DateTime. Since you are grouping based on DateTime the difference has to be between the groups. Inside the groups, all the dates are the same.

Comment: I have edited the question with the exact output which I am trying to get. Thanks !!

Comment: Can you check the answer again please?

Comment: Have given the current and expected output !!

Comment: The code I added to the end of the answer matches your expected output I think.

Comment: Yes, it works well for first group, but for the second group, it does subtract from the previous DateTime, but I need that to start from the beginning. (Please see the difference in 5th row of the current and expected output)

Comment: It does that. Can you check again? The last part of the answer?

Comment: Thanks !! This displays only the aggregated column, i.e. DateTime column. I need the other columns to be displayed the DateTime column along with other columns like MachineName and localIPAdrress.

Comment: And right below it I explained how you can add it to the dataframe.

Comment: Its perfect, Thank you very much !!